# Google Cloud Endpoint is empty (APIs explorer)

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-cloud-platform, endpoint, google-cloud-sdk

I've created a Google Cloud Endpoint with Maven (through Eclipse with the Cloud Tools plugins). To check if all is working, I've created this classes:

```
@Entity
public class Test{        
    @Id private String id;
...
more code
...

}
```

Endpoint:

```
@Api(
    name = "Backend",
    version = "v1",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "backend.com",
            ownerName = "backend.com",
            packagePath = ""
    )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(path = "test",name = "test", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public InterfaceReturn uploadPoster(@Named("magic_word") String magic_word, @Named("description") String description) {
    InterfaceReturn interfaceReturn;
    Test test = new Test();
    ofy().save().entity(test).now();
    interfaceReturn = new InterfaceReturn(200, test);
    return interfaceReturn;
}
```

}

EntityRegistration:

```
public class EntityRegistration {

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Test.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }
    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }

}
```

And other classes like this.

Once I've deployed this version without an error, the apis explorer are not showing any method. It appears absolutely empty and I think that "test" api method should be shown:

[image]

Any idea? I've read a lot of posts but I've not able to solve that problem.

Comment: [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/) shows you APIs from Google. Did you try to look in your [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints)? You should find your endpoints using link like this: https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints?project=<PROJECT_NAME>

Comment: Through that URL, I get the same result :(
Endpoints list are empty... I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Make sure that you are looking in the right project (to which you deployed the endpoint) and are you sure that endpoint got deployed successfully? You can try to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) and deploy a simple HelloWorld API to see if issue still persists.